# Correct datastructure for user specified integer mapping into rows of a matrix

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a C++ class that manipulates an NxM matrix. The rows individually are meaningful, but the C++ contiguous indexing `[0,1,2,...,N-1]` is not. The users find it preferable to choose an indexing which has meaning to them, e.g., for a 3 row matrix, the user may wish to have the integer `-3` label row zero, `-1` label row 1, and `3` label row 2.

I may assume that 1) the labels are integers, and 2) the labels are monotonically increasing, and 3) the number of rows is not huge. I may *not* assume the labels are continuous, or even gapped with even spacing. The pseudocode is below:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::vector<int> labels, int columns) {
        m_.resize(labels.size()*columns);
    }

    void update(int label, T value) {
        // map label to index, update the entry in the matrix:
        int idx = ...;
        m_[idx] = value;
    }

    std::vector<T> get_row(int label) {
         // Map label 
    }
private:
    // A matrix:
    std::vector<T> m_;
    // What datastructure should I use here?
    SomeDataStructure label_to_row_;
};
```

The call to `update` must be extremely fast. What is the best datastructure to use to quickly map the label to the row of the matrix?

Comment: Perhaps an [associative container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Associative_containers) like `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I tried `std::unorder_map` and think it's too slow. Maybe I'm being unrealistic about the performance I can get out of these constraints.

Comment: How did you use the map? What requirements do you have on your project? Especially, what "performance" requirements do you have? And even more important, how did you measure the performance?

Comment: Measured the performance with perf and google benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, hash maps are the fastest containers for what you're trying to achieve (with `O(1)`) complexity. But in practice, there are a couple of things you can do.

First of all, you can have multiple implementations using different data structures and choose to return one of these based on the given indices at runtime (using abstract classes or other similar ways). You can do this on the structures I propose below and choose one at runtime.

1. If you know that the range of data is small (or you can detect it at runtime), Then the problem is easy. Just create a vector that has the same size as the range of data and set the ordered index in this vector:

```
std::vector<int> indices = {/*data*/};
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(indices.begin(), indices.end());
int min = *minmax.first, max = *minmax.second, range = max - min;
std::vector<int> index_map(range);
for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) index_map[indices[i] - min] = i;
```

I hope you got what I'm trying to say because I feel like I didn't explain it very well.

2. If your range of data is large but the minimum spacing between them is also larger than 1, then you can do the previous method with a small modification:

```
std::vector<int> indices = {/*data*/};
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(indices.begin(), indices.end());
int min = *minmax.first, max = *minmax.second, range = max - min;

// Assuming indices are sorted
int diff = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size() - 1; ++i) diff = std::min(diff, indices[i] - indices[i + 1]);

// diff can't be zero
std::vector<int> index_map(range);
for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) index_map[(indices[i] - min) / diff] = i;
```

Here we find the minimum spacing between indices and divide by that.

3. Use an optimized 3rd party map that is optimized further (using vectorization, multi-threading, and other methods) like [these](https://martin.ankerl.com/2019/04/01/hashmap-benchmarks-01-overview/).
4. Maybe you can try to use a weaker but faster hash function since the number of indices are not large.

I'll add to the list if I think of anything else.